# How to hide the Scroll bar still Scrolling?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have some problem that Scroll bar.

I use the Scroll Function in Panel to Look information

but Scroll bar make to shorten information cause width size is fix

so i want to remove or hide the scroll bar

do you have any solving this problem?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so here it is, vb.net, tested, panel2 inside panel1, panel2's width a bit bigger than panel1:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False
    Panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = False

    Panel2.AutoScroll = True
    Panel2.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False
    Panel2.VerticalScroll.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseWheel
    If Panel2.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) Then
        Dim vScrollPosition As Integer = Panel2.VerticalScroll.Value
        vScrollPosition = e.Location.Y
        Panel2.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseEnter
    Panel2.Select()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i added the code but it doesn't work
panel1.autoscroll = true///
panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = False///
panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False

Comment: Are you saying you want the panel to grow in height instead of scrolling?

Comment: no height is also FIXED. so i want scrolling like mobile web surfing. is it possible?

Comment: Ahhh you want it scrollable but without scrollbars, i think you need to override the panel's code to make the vertical scrollbar invisible but keep its functionality

Comment: how could i can? Devcon.. That's too hard;

Comment: You have to put 2 panels inside each other and make the width of the panel inside bigger than the other like so http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?685577-How-to-hide-panel-scrollbar

Comment: Edited my answer and changed some code from the link i provided earlier

Answer (score 0):

you simply use this where you need in the code to deactivate the scrolls.Try it

```
panel1.AutoScroll = false;
```